# Node-webkit protecting data

Tags: node.js, exe, node-webkit, packing

How to pack, distribute and protect data when using node-webkit and creating executable app. I use Enigma Virtual Box to create packed app.exe (Following instructions from [node-webkit github](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps)). But I must have a data folder in which my data.db file is. (I am using NeDB for data persistence). That file is accessible to every user and it can be changed easily with text editor. Is there a way to protect that data or is there better way for distributing app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module to store crypted information in your db .